# Can't compare an attribute from a xml tag

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, sax

So, i'm trying to parse some xml that looks this way:

```
<image size="extralarge">
http://...
</image>
```

But I can't manage to compare the value of attr with a String.
Here's my code :

```
    albumImage.setTextElementListener(new TextElementListener() {
        boolean imageGoodSize=true;
        @Override
        public void start(Attributes attributes) {
            Log.v(TAG_LASTFM, "Image #" + attributes.getValue("size") + "#");
            if(attributes.getValue("size")+"" == "extralarge" || attributes.getValue("size")+"" == "mega") {
                imageGoodSize=false;
                Log.w(TAG_LASTFM, "(imageGoodSize set to false");
            }
            else {
                imageGoodSize=true;
            }
        }
```

In the log, it shows that size is set to "extralarge", But when i try to compare it to the string "extralarge", imageGoodSize isn't set to false. What am I doing wrong ?

Here is the log :

```
06-21 01:52:30.463: V/ParseMusic_LastFM(32610): Image #extralarge#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not compare Strings in Java with the `==` operator. You need to use `.equals("extralarge")`

`==` compare the reference to the String, whereas `.equals` compare the content.